# 2D Collision detection not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision, detection

I've been trying to get collision to work but so far no good.

[Screenshot Unity](http://puu.sh/ei5f5/66105443a7.png)

This is my moveBall.cs which I put on my Ball Object.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class moveBall : MonoBehaviour {

float balSnelheid = 1;

void Update () {
    transform.Translate (0, balSnelheid * Time.deltaTime, 0);
}

void OnCollisionTrigger2D (Collision2D coll) {
    if (coll.gameObject.name == "Brick") {
        Destroy(coll.gameObject);
    }
  }
}
```

And this is my movePlayer.cs which I put on my Player Object.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class movePlayer : MonoBehaviour {

public float snelheid;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    Screen.showCursor = false;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    if (transform.position.x + Input.GetAxis ("hor") * snelheid * Time.deltaTime < 2.9) {
        if (transform.position.x + Input.GetAxis ("hor") * snelheid * Time.deltaTime > -2.9) {
            transform.Translate(Input.GetAxis("hor") * snelheid * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
        }
    }

    if (transform.position.x + Input.GetAxis ("hor") * snelheid * Time.deltaTime > 3) {
        transform.position = new Vector3(2.9f, -4.7f, 0);
    } else if (transform.position.x + Input.GetAxis ("hor") * snelheid * Time.deltaTime < -3) {
        transform.position = new Vector3(-2.9f, -4.7f, 0);
    }
  }
}
```

If anyone could give me a tip/solution it would help me out a lot!

Comment: What exactly is happening as opposed to what you want to happen? The image doesn't tell me much without a description

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One issue I see right off the bat is that you are using the RigidBody component rather than the RigidBody2D component. You need to be careful which components you use.

Also, [OnTriggerEnter2D()](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerEnter2D.html) or [OnCollisionEnter2D()](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider2D.OnCollisionEnter2D.html) is what you are looking for, not OnCollisionTrigger2D.

If using the the 3d components was by choice, please look at [OnCollisionEnter()](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionEnter.html) or [OnTriggerEnter()](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerEnter.html)

Comment: Thanks alot, it's working now. I totally overlooked the Rigidbody2D and colliders 2D. And I was testing with the OnCollisionTrigger2D since it wasn't working with OnCollisionEnter2D and aparently forgot to change it back. Again thanks alot!

Comment: Great answer, +1. I would also add that you can't collide 2D colliders with 3D.